# How to use WHERE on attribute in XML column in Sql Server 2008

Tags: .net, sql-server, xml, sqlxml

This is probably simple and I just don't get the braces right, but since I have virtually no experience in querying SQL SERVER XML data, it's driving me insane.

I have a simple table with an XML typed column *NoSqlField*. This contains either NULL or

```
<root version="1.0">
  <entry key="mykey">1</entry>
</root>
```

I want all rows in the table that have a <entry key="mykey">1</entry> value in their *NoSqlField* column.

A (rather stupid as it uses .ToString()) LINQ query using

```
where h.NoSqlField.ToString().IndexOf("<entry key=\"mykey\">1</entry>") > -1
```

returns a result, so it's definitely there.

**How can I run the same query in T-SQL?** I have tried

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 
NoSqlField.value('(//entry[@key=mykey])[1]','varchar(1)') = '1'
```

in various variations (with and without slashes, full path,...) but never got a single returned row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**
If you want to check if the `NoSqlField` column has an `//root/entry` element and this element contains `1` (inner text) then you could use this solution:

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;
GO

DECLARE @TestData TABLE (
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    NoSqlField XML NULL
);

INSERT  @TestData  (NoSqlField)
SELECT  NULL 
UNION ALL
SELECT  '
<root version="1.0">
  <entry key="mykey">1</entry>
</root>'
UNION ALL
SELECT  '
<root version="1.0">
  <entry key="mykey" anotherkey="myanotherkey">1</entry>
</root>'
UNION ALL
SELECT  '
<root version="1.0">
  <entry key="anotherkey" key2="a">1</entry>
</root>'
UNION ALL
SELECT  '
<root version="1.0">
  <entry key="mykey" key3="3">22</entry>
</root>';

SELECT  * 
FROM    @TestData t
WHERE   t.NoSqlField.exist('//root/entry[@key="mykey"][text() = "1"]') = 1
```

Results:

```
ID NoSqlField
-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2  <root version="1.0"><entry key="mykey">1</entry></root>
3  <root version="1.0"><entry key="mykey" anotherkey="myanotherkey">1</entry></root>
```

Note 1: you can see that this solution allows (the existence of) other attributes (ex. `anotherkey`).

**Solution 2:**
If you want a strict filter (the `entry` element with just one attribute: `key`) then you could use this query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM
(
        SELECT  * 
                ,t.NoSqlField.exist('//root/entry[@key="mykey"][text() = 1]') AS XmlExist
                ,t.NoSqlField.query('
                    let $list := //root/entry/@*
                    for $i in $list
                    where local-name($i) != "key"
                        return <ret value="1"/>
                ').exist('//ret') AS HasAnotherAttribute
        FROM    @TestData t
) src
WHERE   src.XmlExist = 1
AND     src.HasAnotherAttribute = 0
```

Results:

```
ID NoSqlField                                              XmlExist HasAnotherAttribute
-- ------------------------------------------------------- -------- -------------------
2  <root version="1.0"><entry key="mykey">1</entry></root> 1        0
```

Note 2: `let $list := //root/entry/@*` will build a list with all (@*) attributes from `//root/entry` elements.

Note 3: [local-name()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190650.aspx)

Comment: It works (I tried Solution 1 but will definitely study no. 2 as well)! Just like that! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much!